# Cannot open terminal ini nvim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, terminal, linux-ubuntu

I installed Plugin terminal using the [vim-terminal](https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal) plugin and try to execute `:TerminalSplit bash` but before the terminal open I got a warning message.

```
Python 2 interface is not installed, using Python 3 instead
Warning: Global CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocommands may cause Terminal to run slowly
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

after I clicked ENTER, the terminal will appear but it does not give any response when I type any command. Can someone help me with this? here is my `init.vim`. I confuse where is the problem

```
:set number
:set autoindent
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set smarttab
:set softtabstop=4
:set mouse=a

call plug#begin()

Plug 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree' " NerdTree
Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary' " For Commenting gcc & gc
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " CTRL + N for multiple cursors
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.1' }
Plug 'https://github.com/xiyaowong/nvim-transparent'
Plug 'https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal'

set encoding=UTF-8
call plug#end()

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

:colorscheme jellybeans


nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
noremap <C-b> :TerminalSplit bash<CR>
noremap <C-v> :TerminalVSplit bash<CR>
noremap <C-n> :TerminalTab bash<CR>

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

"Create a funtion to get the sections contents, name is irrelevant
function! GetSectionContents()
  " Will be refreshed often
  return 'hello world'
endfunction

"Create vim-airline part
call airline#parts#define_function('func','GetSectionContent')

"Replace section y with output of parts function
let g:airline_section_y = airline#section#create_right(['','func'])

let g:airline#extensions#default#layout = [
    \ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    \ [ 'x', 'z', 'error', 'warning', 'y' ]
    \ ]

" Find files using Telescope command-line sugar.
nnoremap <leader>ff <cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fg <cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fb <cmd>Telescope buffers<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fh <cmd>Telescope help_tags<cr>

let g:transparent_enabled = v:true
```

and here is whats inside my `/usr/bin/python..`

```
fhadli@fhadli-GF63-Thin-9RCX:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/python
python              python2.7           python2-config      python3.8           python3-config      python3-pasteurize  python-config       
python2             python2.7-config    python3             python3.8-config    python3-futurize    python3-wsdump
```

after i add `lue require("toogleterm").setup()` in my `~/.config/nvim.init.vim` i got this error

```
Error detected while processing /home/fhadli/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'toggleterm' not found:
        no field package.preload['toggleterm']
        no file './toggleterm.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/toggleterm.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/toggleterm.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/toggleterm/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/toggleterm.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/toggleterm/init.lua'
        no file './toggleterm.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/toggleterm.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/toggleterm.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

Comment: Which version of Vim are you using? What is the output of `:vim version`?

Comment: Unless you need a plugin for a specific purpose, I would stick with `:terminal`

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt i'm sorry, i'm using nvim v0.8.2

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of the following vim commands: `:has('python')`, `:has('python3')`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt this is the result `E492: Not an editor command: :has('python')` and `E492: Not an editor command: :has('python3')`

Comment: Sorry my mistake: `:echo has('python')` and `:echo has('python3')`

Comment: no problem. here are the results. 
`echo has('python')` -> `0` &
`echo has('python3')` -> `1`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the plugin is *very* old and isn't probably up to date anymore. Since you're using `neovim` I'd recommend to pick one of the terminal-plugins from [this list](https://github.com/rockerBOO/awesome-neovim#terminal-integration). You could give [`toggleterm`](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim) a try for example.

Comment: I have tried to install toogle term using VimPlug but it does not work. it there any different if we install using VimPlug dan Packer?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? There shouldn't be a difference if you either use VimPlug or Packer. They just have different features but should do the same.

Comment: after i execute `PlugInstall` the message shows that i have installed toggleterm. but when I open nvim again and type `ToogleTerm size=12` it gave an error `E492: Not an editor command: ToggleTerm size=12`

Comment: Do you have `lua require("toggleterm").setup()` anywhere in your vimscript file? Because without it, toggleterm will not be prepared for your vim session.

Comment: no i dont have it. should i put in inside `.config/nvim/init.vim`?

Comment: after i add `lue require("toogleterm").setup()` in my `~/.config/nvim.init.vim` i got this error *i update the question

Comment: @MuhammadFhadli I edited your config. You can copy+paste my changes from pastebin into your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. https://pastebin.com/mpwvquDu Please reopen neovim after copy+pasting the content to your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and execute `:PlugUpdate` afterwards.